# Nixie Tube driver ICs keep dying

Tags: arduino, nixie

I really need a hand here. I am trying to control an IN-19B nixie tube with an Arduino UNO. I am using a 170v power supply with a 20K resistor on the anode and the k155id1 driver IC. I have got things working fine (cycling through characters) with the small problem that after about 10-60 seconds I will hear a small click/pop noise and multiple characters on the nixie light up, some still cycling but with other digits that are turned on obscuring them. I assume this noise is the nixie driver blowing and causing some cathodes to short to ground. I have checked the voltage I am supplying the chip with from my arduino (5V) and the placement of all jumper cables and everything seems to be wired correctly. I've also tried running the chip at a lower 3.3v in case I was somehow killing it overvolting it or something. (I know this is a bit stupid because the IC definitely runs at 5v but I was desperate at this point)

I would be eternally grateful if someone could shed some light on this situation. The graveyard of drivers on my desk is growing :(. I have contacted the eBay seller that supplied me with the drivers and they are equally confused. Below you should find the schematic I am using, relevant data sheets and an image of my setup. (I am aware the name of the driver on the schematic and in my circuit are different but from what I saw online the name is the only difference between the two)

I am hoping to use theses tubes in a project for my art A Level so you really would be saving my life if you helped. Thank you. :)

[image: Circuit Schematic]

[image: Driver data sheet]

[image: Nixie data sheet]

[image: Overall setup view[![][4]]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VItZD.jpg)

Update:

The problem appears to be solved after re positioning and replacing the resistor on the breadboard all is functioning correctly.

[image: Repositioned resistor]

[image: efully functional nixie!]

Thank you everyone for your help and very well spotted. I'll make sure to learn from mistakes like this and hope this informs others that see this.

Update 2:

Slightly worrying development. The chip I tried after the fix just did the same thing. This time it took an hour instead of 10 seconds which is definitely an improvement but still sub optimal.

Update 3:

Through sheer incompetence I misunderstood the instructions about the resistor. I believe this should work. Really sorry about that everyone. I remember thinking the pink tinge to the cathode was odd. Assumed it was just variation in tubes but with the colour difference after re positioning the resistor it was obviously a cry for help. Thank you everyone again apologies for my incompetence I will also make sure to learn from this.

[image: Fix after misinterpritation]

Comment: You should always add decoupling capacitors across the power rails of all your ICs as close as possible to the IC. Rule of thumb is 10 to 100nF. Use ceramics capacitors. This may not be your actual issue, but it does prevent a bunch of unpredictable issues from happening.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try adding these to the circuit tomorrow and test the results.

Comment: The resistor shown in the photo afer "Update" does nothing - it is shorted by the power bus on the edge of the breadboard.

Comment: Oh damn I get what you mean now. Sorry inexperience showing through again. Will post another image showing what I now think you mean.

Comment: Your latest fix is correct, does it work now? (btw the pink tinge is probably caused by mercury vapour in your bulb. A lot of tubes have it, as it enhances their longevity. Take care not to break it though!)

Comment: Yes sir everything is working. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a common mistake, and almost invariably for this type of fault you are allowing an illegal state on the decoder chip inputs.
There is NOTHING wrong with using 170-180V for your supply but you must ABSOLUTELY ENSURE that there is always one digit in the 'ON' condition. These Nixie tubes were designed in an era when small scale logic (counters) were used. The counter designs typically did not support illegal states, so the issue was moot. With the use of MCU's proliferating today, the issue of programmed states has to be considered.

The datasheet for the [74141](https://neon1.net/nixieclock/sn74141.pdf) shows the problem clearly:

[image]

DO NOT reduce your supply to 55V + strike voltage as you will have problems turning on your digits. You need to have about 20-50V across your 20k Ohm resistor to allow for. Also be aware that the strike voltage rises when the tube is cold.

Since you are driving your decoder from a microprocessor the port pins you are using are set to inputs when the MCU first starts up. the inputs to the decoder will therefore be high and ALL digits will be off. During this time you are imposing a severe over-voltage on the driver outputs. Current will flow through the zener diodes and the weakest zener will pop.....then the next....then the next and so on.
The zeners fail short circuit mostly hence the digits all start to come on.

The easiest solution is to put an output pull-down resistor on your drive pins to the decoder to handle the power up situation. 
You have to program your MCU to never use the illegal states....ie always have one digit enabled, and don't spend time between digits in illegal states.

If you do need digits to be OFF (leading zero suppression) then you need to clamp the anode voltage for that digit.

**Update:** 
To answer a question posed, you only need to pull down one input on the decoder to ensure that you always have legal states on the input. 
The current requirements for A,B,C,D vary with A being the least current. Since a valid low is <= 0.8V this can be achieved by putting a 470 Ohm resister from A to ground. If the port pin is set to an input then A=0 so digit '0' will be on. 
When the MCU is driving correctly it will have to source 11mA which is well withing rating. 
You still need to ensure that when program your port pins and they are set to outputs that you handle the values to ensure you don't get an illegal state.

Comment: "don't spend time between digits in illegal states." How far do you have to go to achieve this? (i.e. do you have to go so far as to write to the entire GPIO register in a single write? instead of manipulating the GPIO pin by pin atomically?)

Comment: Hmm, this passage is not correct: "There is NOTHING wrong with using 170-180V for your supply but you must ABSOLUTELY ENSURE that there is always one digit in the 'ON' condition.". I have a Nixie clock built myself, uses 74141, and it's "display=off" state is implemented by sending state 15 to all decoders. They have been surviving this for *years*.

Comment: Would posting the code I am using help here? If I was to attempt this solution what value of pull down resistor would you recommend? I'm also not completely clear where exactly the resistor needs to be placed but this is likely my lack of experience showing through. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @anrieff Not sure what you are saying since you don't explain what you anode resistance or high voltage is. I reiterate though ....there is absolutely nothing wrong with having 170-180V high voltage if the design accommodates this. We have no way to jusdge what you design is.

Comment: @DKNguyen The programming is relatively safe once you have at least one pulldown resistor (initial powerup is the real hazard). Since the digit you are about to turn of is conducting, it will continue to conduct current into the zener for a short time. In the meantime you program another digit to be on (micro seconds). If you take too long in the illegal states then you certainly can pop an output zener, but I've never had problems with sequential writes where the delay is only a few microseconds at most.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Even though the issue is fixed I will still look into doing this to avoid other future issues.

Comment: @JackCreasey, my anode resistance is 10k, voltage is 160-170V. I'm not doing any special precautions about invalid states, but of course the MCU starts up quicker than the HV supply ramps up. I'm 100% sure that keeping a digit blanked indefinitely via the "off" states 11-15 is the expected way to use a 74141, and my clock's decoders have been working like that without burning out for years.

Comment: @anrieff Then I'd suggest that you have a couple of issues !) You seem to have too much current flowing for most of the Nixies I've dealt with. 2) If you blank by using illegal states then you have significant current flowing through the lowest value zener on each 74141 device. It may have worked out for you so far, but I'd suggest it's poor design. There is lots of commentary on using illegal states....and you certainly should (IMO) not do it. I typically uses FETs to drive the cathodes and don't use the old style decoder at all.

Comment: @JackCreasey, 1) it's a multiplexed anode display, using 3 decoders for a total of 6 digits; 2) using the "illegal" states are allowed and even recommended in the very datasheet you linked, for blanking out leading zeros. As I said my Nixie clock has been working for years on that design, with no ill effects. Yes, there's probably some leakage current through the zeners, but it doesn't cause a digit to light up, so I'd guess it is quite insubstantial.

Comment: @JackCreasey on your "use FETs for the cathodes" suggestion — this only really feasible if you're willing to lay out and solder 30 to 60 transistors. With modern fabrication (autoroute, SMD, pick&place) this is okay. If you're doing a homebrew job then the dedicated ICs are **much** more convenient.

Comment: @anrieff The datasheet DOES NOT recommend use of illegal states ...what it does say is that "with a minimum external circuitry can use these illegal states to blank leading/trailing digits" So one should interpret this to mean that some external circuitry IS required when using the illegal states for blanking. I've been exposed to these over the decades....and worked on many Nixie counters where the Anode voltage was switched for blanking to prevent too much current through the zeners.

Comment: @JackCreasey, as I said I can try tomorrow to measure what this "too much current" really is. I believe it is in the µA range (because if I probe the cathode voltages with a DMM, the tiny bias currents to the voltmeter are enough to make a digit light up dimly; the 74141's leakage current from the blanking states is therefore smaller, because the tube is completely dark). I also believe what they mean by "minimum external circuitry" is just the anode resistor. If you had one anode switch per each tube, then why use 74141 at all, why not 7441?

Comment: @JackCreasey, I did the experiments proposed. I have К155ИД1 only though. The leakage current is around 0.1µA or less with a scheme like +70V→[10kΩ]→[К155ИД1 collector]→GND, with an illegal input state. 10 cathodes consume say 1µA, this is an order of magnitude less than a *milliwatt* wasted in the decoder.

Comment: ... but I do have to take back my words that the decoders can withstand +160V. They don't. The leakage increases sharply above 75V at the collector. The Nixie tube's nonlinear IV response is very important, it presents itself as nearly an open circuit when the decoders are blank. Most of the voltage drop from 160V is in them, the К155ИД1's collectors only "see" 20-30 volts when a tube is blank.

Comment: @anrieff It's not that the leakage increases above 75V in your case. The zeners conduct at their knee voltage ....which would not really be considered leakage. The voltage seen on the driver output (20V in your case) is due to leakage, and probably dominated by the output transistor leakage. The current flow is highly (IMO) variable and you should be able to easily measure the difference between dark and light currents for the digits.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell from the photos, but it looks to me like you may have shorted out the 20K resistor on the breadboard, which will yield the kind of unfortunate results that you are seeing.

Comment: Good catch! As you say - hard to see but well worth looking at.

Comment: Very well spotted. I have isolated it and tried again but had the same result unfortunately. I really appreciate the idea though.

Comment: This is quite possibly the answer. @CallumCooper, please update your question with new photos after the fix suggested here.

Comment: It looks like I am eating my words here. After putting in a fresh chip and resistor (Last time just fresh chip) the circuit has worked for the last 3 minutes flawlessly. A new record! Great solve thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the SN74141 is rated to handle a maximum of 60 Vdc on the output pins.

[image]

Find out (measure) what the voltage drop across an ionized digit is and add 55 to that value.  Hopefully, that voltage is higher than minimum ignition (firing) voltage of your Nixie tube.  Adjust your high-voltage supply to be somewhat less than that value.

You will then most likely need to adjust the value of the current-limit resistor to achieve the desired current.

I would guess that there are numerous articles available via Google that show how to use that chip to drive the Nixie tubes that are currently available.

Comment: This is very interesting thank you. Another answer has suggested this may cause difficulty making digits light up but if other solutions don't work this sounds like a good option. Thanks again :)

Comment: > "If I recall correctly, the SN74141 is rated to handle a maximum of 55 Vdc on the output pins. "
No, this is not the case. It can handle 160 volts.

Comment: @anrieff Absolutely NOT. The zeners on the output of the 74141 are about 60-65V. Look at the datasheet. https://neon1.net/nixieclock/sn74141.pdf

Comment: @JackCreasey, where do you get that values from the datasheet? The "Off-state output voltage" parameter?

Comment: @anrieff I added it to Dwayne's answer......direct form the TI datasheet.

Comment: @JackCreasey, this isn't an absolute maximum rating. I guess at higher collector voltages the leakage currents become substantial, hence the recommendation. I have some К155ИД1s and I can try that tomorrow in the office if you're curious.